# Index into a mmap?

Tags: malloc, c99, mmap

I'm trying to create an array of structs as a sort of rudimentary cache.

Given a void* pointer to a mmap, does mmap provide any affordances for indexing into it? I think conceptually a mmap is simply providing a block of memory, but then I'm a bit confused as to what I can do with it. Can I just think of it as a malloc?

```
void * mptr = mmap(NULL, 1024*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Thanks for any clarification here.

Comment: Rather think of it as mmap :) mmap will map data to virtual memory addresses which the CPU will translate into physical addresses using the MMU. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit. You can do a lot with mmap, e.g. read/write the virtual memory addresses and also execute code on it using PROT_EXEC. You can create anonymous addresses, you can share the virtual addresses between processes with MAP_SHARED etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can think of it as a malloc, but you must deallocate it with munmap(mptr,1024*1024) rather than free(mptr).

If you want to index into it, cast it to another type, for example char:

```
char *cptr = (char*) mptr;
```

Then you can index into it using cptr[10], for example.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what allocator you're using (`mmap`, `malloc`, `sbrk`, ...) you're still left with a pointer to memory.  Before you can use the memory, you must tell if compiler what **types** live in that memory.  Use C-style or C++ casting to tell the compiler how to treat memory.